# kickstart logical volume on specific disk

Tags: lvm, centos7, kickstart

Is it possible, in kickstart, to specify which physical volume a logical volume gets created in?

I have:

```
clearpart --all --initlabel --drives=sda,sdb,sdc,sdd
zerombr
part /boot --asprimary --fstype="ext4" --ondisk=sdb --size=515
part pv.001 --asprimary --ondisk=sdb --size=1024 --grow
part pv.002 --asprimary --ondisk=sda --size=10240 --grow
#
volgroup rootvg pv.001 pv.002
logvol /       --fstype=xfs  --name=rootlv   --vgname=rootvg  --size=10240
logvol swap    --fstype=swap --name=swaplv   --vgname=rootvg  --size=32768
logvol /home   --fstype=xfs  --name=homelv   --vgname=rootvg  -size=10240
logvol /usr    --fstype=xfs  --name=usrlv    --vgname=rootvg  --size=10240
logvol /tmp    --fstype=xfs  --name=tmplv    --vgname=rootvg  --size=2048
logvol /varlv  --fstype=xfs  --name=varlv    --vgname=rootvg  --size=524288
```

I would like to have rootlv, swaplv and homelv on sdb and the rest on sda.

Is there an option to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a level of indirection.

A *logical volume* is created in a *volume group*, which itself is comprised of one or more *physical volumes* in various possible topologies (not all of which can be constructed in kickstart, but that's irrelevant here).

To put the LV in a different PV, the VG containing it must be on the desired PV. So, you need to create a second VG, and assign the PV to only that VG. For example:

```
volgroup rootvg pv.001
volgroup othervg pv.002
```

Then you can assign LVs to the `othervg` VG. For example:

```
logvol /usr    --fstype=xfs  --name=usrlv    --vgname=othervg  --size=10240
```

You should also reconsider your names. Having "lv" and "vg" in names is redundant and unnecessary. It's always obvious which is which.